# Type: dynamic Undefined name 'DefaultFirebaseOptions'. Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, kotlin

This is my initial_bindings.dart. I am trying to integrate my app to firebase and I get this error everytime I try to run it through an emulator.

```
import 'package:grabbit_v6/data/apiClient/api_client.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import '../../firebase_options.dart';

class InitialBindings extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() async {
    Get.put(PrefUtils());
    Get.put(ApiClient());
    Connectivity connectivity = Connectivity();
    Get.put(NetworkInfo(
        // ignore: todo
        connectivity)); //TODO : run command "flutterfire configure" to generate firebase_options file
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the values from firebase

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: "Api key here",
      appId: "App id here",
      messagingSenderId: "Messaging sender id here",
      projectId: "project id here",
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [FlutterFire Getting Started documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/cli)

Steps:

1. Install flutter fire using command `dart pub global activate flutterfire_cli`
2. Make sure flutter fire cli is added in your system's path
3. Run the command `flutterfire configure`

This command will list out all your firebase projects & allow you to choose the project you want to use. Once this command completes successfully, it should generate a file 'firebase_options.dart' from which you can import `DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform`